# Formula To Calculate An Agreements Remaining Value With An Escalator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been beating my head against the wall and am looking for a little help in writing up a formula to calculate the remaining value of agreements. A while ago I created a calculator (Link Below as Value Calc) that would calculate a lease agreements total value over the length of the lease. This has worked great as most of the variables were fixed or slightly different. However I now need to calculate 100's of agreements remaining value. Not exactly time efficient to plug in each agreement on a 1 by 1 basis.

This [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x716u.jpg) is from the included Lease Id document. What I am struggling to do is for each row tally up the current annual rent amount (Column N) with how long is remaining in the lease (Column K & L) while applying the escalator percentage (Column P) at the appropriate interval (Column Q) and coming up with a total.

For Instance if an agreement had a annual rent of $1200, with 2 years and 2 months remaining in the lease, a 3% escalator that applies itself each year. The value would come out to

**2023** - $200 (Remaining 2 Months of year)

**2024** - $1,236.00 (3% Escalator Applied to the previous year rent of $1200)

**2025** - $1,273.08 (3% Escalator Applied to the previous year rent of $1236)

**Remaining Lease Value** - $2,709.08

I have been racking my brain all day on how to write something to accomplish this task in bulk without having to do each row individually.

[Lease ID](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wwe3xmrLRQD6HULlDa3NBpqeFfEyUBsr/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102720600064113628014&rtpof=true&sd=true)

[Value Calc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xhTMQEgnNQYdKJQ52kyqsJ0p-wdgCNYa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102720600064113628014&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Excel D365, but I believe you can achieve the same in Google Sheets if you use the same support columns as demonstrated below.

To solve your problem, I am using data from Columns K, L, M, N, P, Q, and R from your LEASE ID sheet. I have assumed that the rent will compound monthly (not daily), and I have assumed the current month is 1 Nov 2023 (I have given a name to this date in my solution, which is CurrMth, you will notice I used this name in my formula).

In the first support column, let's work out the total remaining months using the following formula in Cell S3 (and drag it down to apply across)

```
=--TEXTBEFORE(K3," ")*12+(--TEXTBEFORE(L3," "))
```

In the second support column, let's work out the number of months before the next rental increase using the following formula in Cell T3 (and drag it down to apply across)

```
=INT(MAX(0,DAYS(R3,CurrMth))/30)
```

In the third support column, let's show the increase interval in months using the following formula in Cell U3 (and drag it down to apply across)

```
=IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(Q3," "),0)*12
```

In the fourth support column, let's work out the number of increases that will take place in the rest of the lease terms using the following formula in Cell V3 (and drag it down to apply across)

```
=IFERROR(INT((S3-T3)/U3),0)
```

Lastly, let's work out the remaining payables using the following formula in Cell W3 and drag it down to apply across. You could google the use of FV formula, which you may find useful when working with leases.

```
=IF(T3=0,N3*S3,T3*N3+FV(P3,V3,-M3*(U3/12),,1))
```

[image: Solution]

No fancy formulas are used. To solve a complicated problem, I recommend breaking down the key elements and using simple formulas to work out the desired value, and then the solution will surface.

If you are using Excel D365, you could potentially using the LET function to consolidate all the supporting elements into one 'monster' formula, such as the below:

```
=LET(
     MthLeft,--TEXTBEFORE(K3," ")*12+(--TEXTBEFORE(L3," ")),
     MthNoIncr,INT(MAX(0,DAYS(R3,CurrMth))/30),
     IncrInterval,IFERROR(--TEXTBEFORE(Q3," "),0)*12,
     IncrTimes,IFERROR(INT((MthLeft-MthNoIncr)/IncrInterval),0),
     IF(MthNoIncr=0,N3*MthLeft,MthNoIncr*N3+FV(P3,IncrTimes,-M3*(IncrInterval/12),,1)))
```

In your LEASE ID sheet, in Cell S3, you could enter the above formula and still get the same results. The LET function allows you to define names to each of the supporting calculations, and then use those names in the final calculation, which is the IF formula in the last bit of the formula.

I am sure my formulas can been simplified further, suggestions are welcomed :]